# 3-D function that follows an inverse square law, but has an overall integral equal to a constant

Tags: inverse, infinity, square-numbers

I'm currently trying to figure out a 3D function which follows the "inverse square law" along any given ray drawn from 0,0,0 coordinates, but whose -inf..inf integral over all arguments converges.

Such function is great, but it does not converge:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

The closest function that converges I've found is:
$$\frac{1}{1+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$$
But it's "inverse quad law" or something.

Not sure it's possible to find such function, but asking won't hurt I guess...

Comment: what if I convolve this "quad" function in FFT domain by a 1/(1+x^0.5) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the general case, but if you want your function to be of the form $f(r)$ with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, then it's not possible. Proof:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} F(x, y, z)  = 4\pi \int_0^\infty f(r)r^2\ dr
$$

If you want this to converge, then $f(r)r^2$ must go as $r^{-(1+p)}$, with $p>0$. But this implies that $f(r)$ must go as $r^{-(3+p)}$.

Comment: I'm not sure... but I do not need to find roots, just need an integrable function